# The use of "that of" with a percentage

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> DHT concentration with the Low Carb diet was 58% that of the CRPC-bearing mice on the Western diet.

I know a comparison is made, but I don't know if it is saying that the low carb diet was 58% more, or less, than the western diet.

Answer (score 1):

If A is 58% *of* B, that means that A = 58/100 * B. "That of" is used to refer to an aspect of something. In this case, it refers to DHT concentration, so the whole thing means "DHT concentration *with the Low Carb diet* was 58% of the DHT concentration *with* the CRPC-bearing mice *on the Western diet*." So a little more than half.

"A is 58% less than B" and "A is 58% more than B" are used to refer to percentages greater or less than 100% *of* B — 42% of B (so less than half) and 158% of B (so more than one and a half times) respectively.

This also applies to other fractions. "A is a third more than B" means A is one and one third times as much as B, but "A is a third of B" means A is just one third times as much.